# Какую книгу по Django можете посоветовать?

Tags: django

Всем привет! Я изучаю Django и сейчас пришел к тому, что мне нужна книга, чтобы получать структурированную информацию. Проблема в том, что большая часть книг написана про версию 1 или 2, а хотелось бы про 3. Так вот, есть какие-то рекомендации (также, было бы интересно узнать про какие нибудь курсы)?
Всем печенек!)

Comment: Книг по `3.x` нет. Можете читать по `2.x`, они ещё актуальные

Comment: [Веб-фреймворк Django (Python)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django).

Comment: [Django Girls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/).

Answer (score 0):

Python - разработка на Django
Советую так как с неё начинал!
Курсы советую на курсера посмотреть